# Collaboration portal approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

The company I work for has recently taken over a SharePoint 2007 project form another company. The other company created a site using the Collaboration Portal Publishing template. Since this is an internet web site, this is causing me a couple of problems.

By default the approval workflow is not activated on the Pages Libraries of the site, and the client requires the workflow to be active on all of the Pages Libraries. The problem is that the site is massive, and doing this manually will take too long, and because it’s such a large site I can’t recreate it from scratch.

Is there a way I can activate the approval workflow on all the Pages Libraries of the site? Could I maybe change something in the site definition? Or is there a way to activate it programmatically? Then I could create a console app that will recursively iterate through the sites and attach the workflow to the Pages Libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Your can try with this code :

```
using (MossFramework.DocumentLibraryHelper docLibraryHelper = new MossFramework.DocumentLibraryHelper("SITENAME"))
{
   using (SPSite site = new SPSite(docLibraryHelper.MossSiteAddress))
   {
     SPWeb siteCollection = site.OpenWeb();
     siteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
     SPFolder folder = siteCollection.GetFolder("Document Centre");
     SPList list = siteCollection.Lists["Document Centre"];
     Guid wfBaseId = new Guid("{5703E6AC-1C65-440F-88DC-EB65F2C6DF82}");
     SPWorkflowAssociation wrkFl = list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByBaseID(wfBaseId);
     foreach (SPListItem spListItem in list.Items)
     {
       site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(spListItem, wrkFl, wrkFl.AssociationData);
       // Error occurs here
     }
     site.Close();
   }
}
```

or
[You can try with this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/6765e73a-a3bb-4f0a-9d9e-532bd40fd147)

I hope that helps